# How to vertically position the page number at the height of a TikZ picture in a footer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, fancyhdr

In the following picture, my page number is higher than my rectangle.
I'd like the page number to be lower. Really lower.
The best for me would be to have both the rectangle and the page number vertically centered between the horizontal line and the bottom of the page.

I tried to play with some "parameters", but I don't know what I'm doing.
And even if I "succeeded", I wouldn't understand why...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,top=1cm, bottom=3cm, left=1cm, right=1cm, twoside=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
some text
\fancyfoot[C]{%
\begin{figure}[H]%
\centering%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\filldraw [red] (0,0) rectangle (10,0.5);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}%
}%
\fancyfoot[RO, LE] {\thepage}%
\end{document}%
```

[image: page number is too high]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `figure` environment , which adds vertiacal spacing, and you don't need a hammersledge like TiKZ for the rule. Here is a simple solution with basic LaTeX:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[a5paper,top=1cm, bottom=3cm, left=1cm, right=1cm, twoside=true]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{float}

    \begin{document}

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
    some text
    \fancyfoot[C]{%
    \color{red}\rule{10cm}{0.5cm}
    }%
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE] {\thepage}%

    \end{document}%
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get your picture with this LaTeX code. I have tried compiling with pdflatex and lualatex, but the result is the same: a "1" higher than the rectangle.
Is it possible that I've broken something in my LaTeX configuration?
Moreover, I used a simple TikZ rectangle for my MWE, but the real TikZ picture I had the original problem with is a "real" complex TikZ picture.

Comment: @Michaël: If you have a picture that can't  done with basic latex, I suggest removing the figure environment. When I tested with your code, it gave the same result as the posted image. Now, if your  real image has a part under the base line, you can  put in a `\raisebox{some height}{…}` to compensate.

Comment: I didn't know raisebox. It is exactly what I needed. And removing the figure environment as you said already improved the situation. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!